# produce html custom grid list items

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/6jnx7e56/

```
#UL_1 {
    width: 350px;
    perspective-origin: 175px 0px;
    transform-origin: 175px 0px;
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px/normal Arial;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}/*#UL_1*/
```

so far I use float, but how can I keep the position of others if I remove 4 and 6 block? I want to produce a Z shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#LI_8,#LI_12
{
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the opacity to 0 on a spot where you don't want something to be shown perhaps? Otherwise a table could be used; however, it won't be responsive.

```
#LI_8, #LI_12 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**Side note:** You have tons of useless stuff in your CSS. You can clean it up a lot further. Here is some done for you: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jnx7e56/3/)

Comment: I thought bout this but it's not a good solution as I'm integrating this with drag and drop using js. I prefer clean markup

Comment: I don't understand what isn't clean about it really. What about using a table? Absolute/relative coordinates instead of float?